# Maths brain teaser. Fifty minutes ago it was four times as many minutes past three o'clock

Tags: contest-math, education, puzzle

Fifty minutes ago it was four times as many minutes past three o'clock.
How many minutes is it to six o'clock..?

I have got the solution online but have doubts in it :

```
There are 180 minutes between 3 o'clock and 6 o'clock. 

Call x the number of minutes to 6 o'clock. 

Then it is 180 - x minutes past 3 o'clock and 50 minutes ago it was 130 - x minuted past 3 o'clock. 

Using the 4 times as many minutes past three o'clock bit we can form the equation 

130 - x = 4x and solve it 
130 = 5x 
x = 26 so yes it is 26 minutes.
```

According to me :

How it is **4x** in above equation , it should be 4(180-x) , and new equation should be **130-x = 4(180-x)** , because it says that it was 4 times as many minutes past 3:00 PM.

please explain. according to the solution if it is 4x on the RHS of the equation , then according to me the question is wrong , and should be written as :

```
Fifty minutes ago it was four times as many minutes to 6 o'clock.
```

Answer (score 4):

The figure below may help explain (apologies for the sub-optimal formatting)

[image]

Comment: I also had the same figure drawn, but am still confused that why it is = 4x, can you please explain in simple language ?

Comment: The key point is your reference time which is Now (the red line in my figure). The assumption is that Now is $x$ minutes before 6 o'clock. So the time $50$ minutes before Now will be $50+x$ before 6 o'clock. The time 3 o'clock will occur $180$ minutes before 6 o'clock. So $50$ minutes before Now will be $180-(50+x)$ minutes after 3 o'clock, which is $130-x$. You are told that $130-x$ (the minutes after 3 o'clock) is $4$ times the minutes before 6 o'clock, which is $x$. So you have $130-x=4x$.

Comment: but where is this told in the question that  :   "  130−x (the minutes after 3 o'clock) is 4 times the minutes before 6 o'clock   " , but instead it is written in the question that : " 50 mins ago it was four times as many minutes it is NOW past 3 o'clock  "

Comment: To be honest, the question is quite poorly worded. I made the assumption

Answer (score 3):

I think the question means $4$ times as many minutes to $6$ o' clock from now.

Comment: but it isn't mentioned in the question anywhere ? can you please tell me which line tell it.

Comment: That't the inference drawn from the way they solved it. And the question makes no sense if not assumed. What is 4 times? They should have made the language clearer

Answer (score 0):

[image: a little correction]

it says

Fifty minutes ago it was four times as many minutes past three o'clock

IT means X

WAS means =

FOUR TIMES means 4 *

AS MANY MINS PAST 3 means 130-X

so equation becomes X=4*(130-X);
                    X=104 mins

How many mins past 3 = 130-X=130-104= 26mins

example If a Father's age is 2 times the age of Son and Son's age is 30yrs. then the equation will be 
                  X = 2*30; X = 60yrs.
             Not 2X = 30;   X = 15yrs.

Hope this explains the above question.