# Simple Puzzle: A Matter Of Time

Tags: arithmetic, puzzle

I am trying to solve a simple puzzle:

Fifty Minutes ago if it was four times as many minutes past three O'clock, how many minutes is it to six O'clock.

I tried solving it:

Let x be the minutes past 5,
then 120 + x - 50 = 4x

which gives the wrong answer.

The correct solution has the formulation 180 - 50 -x = 4x which gives x = 26 and is the correct answer.

Am I doing weird thing by assuming that x is the minutes past 5 ? My approach is same as the one with correct solution if I use 4(60 -x) on the LHS but why should I ?

Is it that the puzzle is wrong in its formulation or am I missing something and hence am unable to arrive at the correct solution ?

By the way, the puzzle is from a famous book by Shakuntala Devi and hence I am forced to doubt the validity of my approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the time until $6$ is not the same as the time past $5$, treating $x$ this way results in a solution that is based on a false assumption. To remedy this, you would want to re-write the RHS to match with how you have written the LHS.

In order to avoid algebraic acrobatics, consider the problem as such: the "goal" time is $6$, which is $180$ minutes after $3$, but it is presently $x$ minutes prior to $6$. This gives us the $180-x$. Then we have that $50$ minutes ago, it was $4$ times longer after $3$ than it is presently before $6$, and this gives us the $-50$ and the $4x$.

Hence the book's set up is correct. The BIG problem is that the problem has a confusing wording. It would be easier to say: "If the time 50 minutes ago was 4 times as many minutes **past three** as the time now is **before six**, then what time is it now?"

Comment: Yes, but suppose I get this question in an exam, then wouldn't the assumption that the question is talking about x as minutes past 5 more natural than minutes to 6 ?

Comment: And I guess the only puzzling thing in the puzzle was the making the correct assumption of what x would be defined as ?

Comment: Yes. The most puzzling part was understanding the question. As to the exam issue, the set up would just mean being certain to deal with the "minutes past 5" in a way that is equivalent to dealing with "minutes before 6". The only "natural" way to handle it is by using your native customs to tell the time, so I guess you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

The problem (it appeared here already [before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/751588/maths-brain-teaser-fifty-minutes-ago-it-was-four-times-as-many-minutes-past-thr), but without the strange "if") is worded in a completely misleading way. Maybe a mathematical moron from the assessment industry had it translated by Babelfish from a japanese or chinese source.

The sentence "Fifty minutes ago [if] it was four times as many minutes past three o'clock" can only be interpreted as "Fifty Minutes ago it was four times as many minutes past three o'clock *than it is now*" because no other point of comparison is given. If it is now $x$ minutes past three o'clock this means that
$$720+x-50=4x\ ,$$
or $x=3{\rm h}\>43'\>20''$. It follows that it takes another $$11{\rm h}\>16'\>40''$$ until six o'clock.